# How to use datatables.net plugin with asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I've gridview structure like shown in following image.
[image: grid view]

Where column 1 has checkboxes and above buttons will have actions on click based on selected rows.

How can I implement datatables.net plugin with it and load data into it via **jquery-ajax call to web method so that it will give great performance**.

Currently I've just applied plugin to grid view but the whole data is loaded at the time of page load and I've used DataKeys option of gridview to perform action on selected row, but this will not available if I loaded data via jquery ajax call.

Comment: If you want to use `datatables` plugin there is no need to use grid view, you can directly use html table. And the question you are asking here is not about any problem you are facing but you want to know the whole process of implementing datatables for ajax call which is already explained in there website. Have a look here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html and other links.
And welcome to SO :)